# Unable to select file for parent directory using ../

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite

I am setting up multi store view and I have placed `index.php` and `.htaccess` file under the new directory `/home/storeweb/public_html/so/sb/extreme-landing/` but for some reason I am not able to select `Mage.php` file by adding any number of `../` before `app/Mage.php`

I tried by adding single `../` before `app/Mage.php` and I got an error

> /home/storeweb/public_html/so/sb/extreme-landing/../app/Mage.php was
>   not found.

By adding single `../` it should be looking for `Mage.php` under `sb` directory but not sure what is wrong.

**My virtual host entries:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/storeweb/public_html/
    ErrorLog /home/storeweb/logs/domain_error.log
    CustomLog /home/storeweb/logs/domain_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA.crt

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/storeweb/public_html/
    ErrorLog /home/storeweb/logs/domain_error.log
    CustomLog /home/storeweb/logs/domain.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **`index.php`** have below code

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
```

This is define current directory as **`MAGENTO_ROOT`** so:

```
MAGENTO_ROOT : /home/storeweb/public_html/so/sb/
```

Change `index.php` code

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

to:

```
//define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

    $compilerConfig = '../../includes/config.php';
    if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
        include $compilerConfig;
    }

    $mageFilename = '../../app/Mage.php';
```